# Why doesn't my first gets() work? I have some of them and codeblocks always forgets the first one?

Tags: c, string, codeblocks, gets

I'm using gets() cause it's a jomework and we are told to.
It acts like I'd have no gets(&a)...

```
    ` char a,b,c;
      switch(x);
            case '1':printf("Please enter the author\n");
                     printf("Author:");
                     gets(&a);
                     printf("\nTitle:");
                     gets(&b);`
```

Comment: Can you show the definition for the `a` variable?  `gets()` expects a character buffer, and it's rarely called in this way (with the `&` address-of operator).

Comment: Hey there Laszlo and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your situation so we can help you better? :)

Comment: You might want to rethink even using `gets`. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: The first thing you need to know about `gets()` is never to use `gets()`.  It is long ago deprecated and before that one of the C libraries most embarrassing errors.

Comment: No, do not post code in comments. [edit] your post to contain a [mre] instead.

Comment: Code::Blocks includes a debugger - you should use it.   I am willing to bet that it runs `a` is assigned the empty string `""`.  Whatever preceding input function call you have used (probably the one that accepts the `'1'` you are switching on) did not consume the newline ( `scanf( "%c"...)` or `getchar()` perhaps), so the next input function returns immediately because there is input already in the buffer.

Comment: In any case, you will need a buffer longer than one char to input any kind of useful string:(

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't my first gets() work?

`gets(char *);` expects a pointer to a place to form a non-zero length string.

`char a` in only big enough for a zero length `""` string.

`gets(&a);` is buffer overflow - research undefined behavior.

---

"I'm using gets() cause it's a jomework and we are told to." --> Sorry your school/work is so.  Recommend researching for a  better school.